# How to optimize the code of drawing a region?

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, regions

```mathematica
p=2
openDisk[center_,pass_]:=ImplicitRegion[Norm[{x,y}-center,p]<Norm[pass-center,p],{x,y}]
a = {0,0}; b = {2,1}; c = {1,-2}
RegionPlot[
  RegionEqual[
    RegionIntersection[openDisk[a,{x,y}],openDisk[b,{x,y}],openDisk[c,{x,y}]],
    EmptyRegion[2]
  ],
  {x,-2,4},{y,-2,4}
]
```

It runs without output for very long time (I have waited half an hour).
How to optimize it?

Comment: RegionEqual will output True or False, so that is one problem.

Comment: @lericr The first argument of `RegionPlot` needs to be an expression that returns True or False.

Comment: sorry. I misread your code.

Comment: `RegionPlot` has the attribute `HoldAll`. Use `Evaluate` i.e., `RegionPlot[ Evaluate@RegionEqual[RegionIntersection[openDisk[a, {x, y}], openDisk[b, {x, y}], openDisk[c, {x, y}]], EmptyRegion[2]], {x, -2, 4}, {y, -2, 4}]`